# Prizepicks API wont let me bypass the 403 forbidden error

Tags: python

I am having trouble bypassing the 403 forbidden error when trying to get stats from this API. Any pointers on how to get past this? I have a list of headers but these are not getting me past the 403 error.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api.prizepicks.com/projections'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101                 Firefox/115.0',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'  
}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

My output is the 403 forbidden code.